# Changing imports for iOS frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

Suppose I have a framework named `A.framework` with an `A.h` file as the main import. The standard way the client app would use this framework is:

`#import <A/A.h>`

Suppose now there exists another framework `B.framework` whose functionality I want to subsume/override/implement in my `A.framework` so that the client app could actually unlink `B.framework` and only link to `A.framework` to get all of `B.framework`'s functionality. In other words, I have a implemented all of `B.framework`'s functionalities inside `A.framework` and there is a file you would be able to import via

`#import <A/B.h>`

such that if the user replaced all of the `#import <B/B.h>` calls with `#import <A/B.h>`, they would get all of `B.framework`'s functionality.

My question is: can I let the user just unlink `B.framework` without replacing all of their `#import <B/B.h>` calls with `#import <A/B.h>` and somehow have those `#import <B/B.h>` import from `A.framework` instead?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have described it, yes. If all of your classes/methods/etc. are inside `A/B.h` that would be retrieved from `B/B.h`, B.framework is no longer required, as long as A.framework does not reference B.framework directly...if that makes sense...

Think of it this way:

[image: Not allowed]

If you are unlinking B.framework in this case, you will get an error when you try to do anything in B.h because the B.h file in A.framework requires B.framework to function.

However, if it looks like this:

[image: Allowed]

So your essential components of B.framework are actually *inside* A.framework (you consolidated them) i.e. A.framework *never* references `<B/*>`, you are okay to do that!

Hope that helps you.